# Making my video header responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css

Alright, so my website has a video header. I want it to be responsive when shrinking the browser ( or in mobile view ), how can I do that? It works great when looking at it on my monitor but as soon as I shrink the browser window, the video becomes small and a huge white space appears underneath it ( about 500px high ).
Here's the code:

```
    <div class="header-container">
        <div class="video-container">
            <video muted preload="true" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" volume="0" poster="4.png"
                <source src="video/drift.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

 .header-container {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 1000px;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.video-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

video {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0.78;
    width: 100%;
}

.header-container h1 {
    color: #3cbc8d;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 10%;
    border: 3px solid #fffff;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 700px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 100px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    }

.header-container h2 {
    color: #3cbc8d;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border: 3px solid #fffff;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 700px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        }

    <div class="header-container">
        <div class="video-container">
            <video preload="true" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" volume="0" poster="4.png"
                <source src="video/cruise1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
                        <h1>3P4B</h1>
                            <h2>Portable Power Pack for Boating</h2>
                            <div class="letsgo">
                                <a href="#about" class="btn btn-sample hvr-pulse " role="button" style="font-size: 3.5em; border-radius: 50px; text-align: center;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span></a>
                                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try fitvids.js and this library will help you with getting responsive videos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the whitespace beneath the video, is that the video is keeping its aspect ratio in tact while shrinking to follow the screen size. E.g. since you've locked your .header-container class at a min-height of 1000px, the whitespace you're seeing is the background of the .header-container.

EDIT: Background video is now absolutely positioned, to not interfere with overlapping content. .header-container has been set to 94% of screen height, with a max limit of 1000px.

I think this is probably what you're going for with your current setup:

```
.header-container {
  width: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 94%;
  height: 94vh;
  max-height: 1000px;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 10% 0 0 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.video-container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
 }

video {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.78;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -mos-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.header-container h1 {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 80%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #3cbc8d;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 }

.header-container h2 {
  position: relative;
  color: #3cbc8d;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 80%;  
  margin: 25px auto;
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 }
```

See updated pen here:

http://codepen.io/flapjax/pen/zqXKaY

This scales the video to always fill out the entire background width and/or height of the header-container.
It will emulate the 'cover' attribute and cut off some of either the videos height or width to scale it correctly to fill out the header-container.

Comment: Do you need to stack additional elements on top of the header-container?

Comment: Yes, I do. Just applied your solution and it made my h1's go underneath the video. I'll update the question with the css snipper of the h1 and h2.

Comment: Can you please add them to your html also, so I can see your structure?

Comment: Done. Nevermind the first HTML snipper, just look at the one at the bottom.

Comment: Updated the pen and code snippet. Notice, I moved your h1 and h2 tag out of the video-container. As it is now, the video-container only helps contain the background video, and everything overlapping the video, should be placed adjacent to the 'video-container' element. if you want the wrapping white boxes around your text to be smaller, simply set a lower value for the width of the textboxes.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you, Please upload a video of 1920*1080 resolution

Fiddle https://fiddle.jshell.net/3zLx1sdz/